# Como importar um arquivo de extensão .sql no SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Eu recebi um arquivo que ele possui a extensão .sql, portanto toda a vez que importo algo no sql server é das extensões .bak. É possível fazer isso? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ficheiros .sql contêm, normalmente, instruções SQL. Estes ficheiros, ao contrário dos .bak não são importados, mas sim "executados", por exemplo usando o SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

**Atenção** que o ficheiro pode conter SQL indiscriminado o que pode ser bastante perigoso se não estiver certo da sua origem. Sugiro sempre que verifique o seu conteúdo antes de o tentar executar.

Com o SSMS pode simplesmente fazer:

```
- Iniciar o SQL Server Management Studio
- Efectuar a coneção à base de dados
- Ficheiro > Abrir > Seleccionar o ficheiro .sql
- Executar (F5)
```

Se o ficheiro for anormalmente grande (mais do que 50/100MB), pode usar o [sqlcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-start-the-utility?view=sql-server-2017), que se trata de uma ferramenta que normalmente é instalada com o SQL Server e que permite a execução de instruções SQL através de várias formas. Uma das quais permite a execução de instruções de SQL guardados num ficheiro.

Fica aqui um exemplo de utilização:

```
sqlcmd -S NOME_SERVIDOR\INSTANCIA -i C:\caminho\para\ficheiro.sql -o C:\caminho\ficheiro_saida.txt
```

O resultado da execução será guardado no ficheiro ficheiro_saida.txt.